# How can I reuse the same Vim window/buffer for command output, like the :help window?

Tags: vim

Though I'm no Vim expert, I've been scratching an itch by working on [a rough Vim equivalent](https://github.com/henrik/dotfiles/blob/a9f3cb3266617380cf19877d44ff9aa9ce326eff/vimrc#L214-242) of TextMate's ⌘R functionality to run Ruby code from a buffer and display the output.

The script currently just opens a new window (split) with `:new` and puts the output there. If you run it multiple times, it opens multiple windows. Ideally, I'd like it to reuse the same window within each tab page, much like `:help` does.

I've looked but haven't found a way to achieve this. Any pointers?

Comment: Now available here: https://github.com/henrik/vim-ruby-runner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a scratch buffer with a name, so that on subsequent calls you can check to see if that buffer is already open (and if so reuse it) or you need a new one. Something like this:

```
function! Output()
    let winnr = bufwinnr('^_output$')
    if ( winnr >= 0 )
        execute winnr . 'wincmd w'
        execute 'normal ggdG'
    else
        new _output
        setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
    endif
    silent! r! ls
endfunction
```

Comment: After creating a new buffer you should just save its number: `let s:outputbufnr=bufnr('%')` and then check it with `if bufexists(s:outputbufnr)..else..endif`.

Comment: Thanks! This (and ZyX's comment) pointed me in the right direction: https://github.com/henrik/dotfiles/commit/b5b9c9dc94dbcf44008425076a32502e6a9eab4e One difference is that I use `t:varname` to make it tab page local.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it manually.

For Example:

```
:e test1.txt   (or use any existing buffer)
:vs            (or :new or :sp)
:b <tab>       (keep pressing tab until test1.txt comes up. or use the buff no)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the quickfix window so you can also jump to errors. If you get a [ruby compiler vim plugin](https://bitbucket.org/fedesilva/vim/src/79eccf902533/compiler/ruby.vim), you can run `:make` to run your code. You should see output and errors in the quickfix (`:copen`).